# Hierarchical structure with DOT, generating SVG image with Graphviz

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot, jquery-svg

I'm trying to generate a graph with Graphviz using DOT language and apply Javascript to the graph.

The problem is to structure the nodes and edges at a specific level (i.e parents/childs).
The generated svg looks (pseudo) like this:

```
<svg>
   <g>Node 1</g>
   <g>Node 2</g>
   <g>Node 3</g>
   <g>Edge 4</g>
   <g>Edge 5</g>
</svg>
```

I want to use javascript and JQuery to toggle the nodes. When I click on Node 1, then the edges and childs (the first level) should display, and not the childs child etc.

```
$("#SVGContainer").on("click", "g.node", function(){
   $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

So, my question is how can I write the DOT. So graphviz will generate the SVG so I can use the sibblings function?

The output should be something like:

```
<svg>
   <level1>
      <g>Node 1</g>
      <g>Edge 4</g>
      <g>Edge 5</g>
   </level1>
   <level2>
      <g>Node 2</g>
      <g>Node 3</g>
   </level2> 
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Simplified question. Can I add metadata to SVG images (g tag) with the DOT language? How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I associate SVG elements generated by graphviz to elements in the DOT source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146706/how-do-i-associate-svg-elements-generated-by-graphviz-to-elements-in-the-dot-sou)

Comment: I have to assume you don't need an answer to this any more : ) but for searchers - the simplified question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146706/how-do-i-associate-svg-elements-generated-by-graphviz-to-elements-in-the-dot-sou - summary, an alternative to nesting the elements and using the siblings() function is to add css classes to <g> elements with a result being something like `let level1 = d8t.querySelectorAll('.level1'); level1.forEach(el => el.onclick = () => level1.forEach(el => el.classList.add('active')));`