# How do I associate SVG elements generated by graphviz to elements in the DOT source code

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graphviz

So, I've generated an svg graph from the dot file, using viz.js.
Now, it's easy to select it's elements, using javascript, but I don't see any association to the original dot file. I don't see any object structure in viz.js library, that ties the generated svg chart elements to the dot source elements, so, that, if I select the svg element with the mouse, I would know that this svg element is correspondent to the dot element, that it was generated from. Is there a way to have a such feedback? I need this, so that, if I edit an element in svg (visually in the browser), I would be able to map the edit back to the dot file and reflect the change on the source.

### Explanation

#### So, here is the example of a possible source GraphViz dot code:

```
digraph DB {
rankdir=LR
node [shape=record]

person [
    label="
        Person table|
        <id> Person ID|
        <fn> First Name|
        <mn> Middle Name|
        <ln> Last Name
    "
]

address [
    label="
        Addresses table|
        <id> Address ID|
        <pid> Person ID|
        <index> ZIP Code|
        <street> Street Name|
        <house> House Number|
        <town> City/Town/Village Name|
        <state> State Name|
        <district> County/District Name|
        <country> Country Name
    "
]

phone [
    label="
        Phone Number table|
        <pid> Person ID|
        <cc> Country Code|
        <ac> Area Code|
        <n> Phone Number
    "
]
{phone:pid address:pid} -> person:id
}
```

Here is the svg result, generated by Viz.js library (but, as for me, I don't care, if the same can be done by other library, I will use that other library):

```html
<svg width="671pt" height="257pt" viewBox="0 0 671 257" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 253)">
<title>DB</title>
<polygon fill="#ffffff" stroke="transparent" points="-4,4 -4,-253 666.8861,-253 666.8861,4 -4,4"></polygon>
<!-- person -->
<g id="node1" class="node">
<title>person</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="277.8566,-62.5 277.8566,-186.5 371.2234,-186.5 371.2234,-62.5 277.8566,-62.5"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="324.54" y="-169.9" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Person table</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="277.8566,-161.7 371.2234,-161.7 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="324.54" y="-145.1" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Person ID</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="277.8566,-136.9 371.2234,-136.9 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="324.54" y="-120.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">First Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="277.8566,-112.1 371.2234,-112.1 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="324.54" y="-95.5" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Middle Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="277.8566,-87.3 371.2234,-87.3 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="324.54" y="-70.7" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Last Name</text>
</g>
<!-- address -->
<g id="node2" class="node">
<title>address</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-.5 504.1939,-248.5 662.8861,-248.5 662.8861,-.5 504.1939,-.5"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-231.9" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Addresses table</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-223.7 662.8861,-223.7 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-207.1" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Address ID</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-198.9 662.8861,-198.9 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-182.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Person ID</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-174.1 662.8861,-174.1 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-157.5" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">ZIP Code</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-149.3 662.8861,-149.3 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-132.7" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Street Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-124.5 662.8861,-124.5 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-107.9" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">House Number</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-99.7 662.8861,-99.7 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-83.1" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">City/Town/Village Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-74.9 662.8861,-74.9 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-58.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">State Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-50.1 662.8861,-50.1 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-33.5" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">County/District Name</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="504.1939,-25.3 662.8861,-25.3 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="583.54" y="-8.7" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Country Name</text>
</g>
<!-- address&#45;&gt;person -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge">
<title>address-&gt;person:id</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M503.9959,-133.8802C457.4691,-139.3669 403.6776,-145.7102 381.6916,-148.3029"></path>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="381.0613,-144.8529 371.54,-149.5 381.8811,-151.8047 381.0613,-144.8529"></polygon>
</g>
<!-- phone -->
<g id="node3" class="node">
<title>phone</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="0,-62.5 0,-186.5 131.08,-186.5 131.08,-62.5 0,-62.5"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="65.54" y="-169.9" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Phone Number table</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="0,-161.7 131.08,-161.7 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="65.54" y="-145.1" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Person ID</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="0,-136.9 131.08,-136.9 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="65.54" y="-120.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Country Code</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="0,-112.1 131.08,-112.1 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="65.54" y="-95.5" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Area Code</text>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" points="0,-87.3 131.08,-87.3 "></polyline>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="65.54" y="-70.7" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">Phone Number</text>
</g>
<!-- phone&#45;&gt;person -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge">
<title>phone-&gt;person:id</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M131.1663,-132.2389C180.2951,-138.0324 243.0276,-145.4301 267.307,-148.2933"></path>
<polygon fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" points="267.1989,-151.8047 277.54,-149.5 268.0187,-144.8529 267.1989,-151.8047"></polygon>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Let's say, I want to edit the " City/Town/Village Name" in the source dot file not by editing source's text, but by visually clicking on the related generated svg representation of that dot source. I can write some JavaScript, that will allow me to click on "City/Town/Village Name" on the svg graphic, for example, and the block becomes active. Then, I edit it in-place, as I wish. The problem lies with saving the change back to the source. JavaScript should change the dot source accordingly, but the problem is that the svg, generated with viz.js doesn't have any ties to the source. I.e., if you look at the source of the generated svg, it doesn't add any ids or anything, that would indicate, that a particular svg element was generated from which dot element. There is no way to identify, which element was edited in order to pass the edited value back to the correct dot element for the change to be made in the source. There are some ways, that I can think of so solve my issue:

- edit the viz.js library, so it puts some ids on the generated svg
- tediously analyse the generated svg, in order to logically identify the correct source element, to the edited svg element

,but the above are too difficult jobs and would take a long time to accomplish, so, I am asking, if there is some feature in viz.js, that I've missed, that would allow me to accomplish my task, or maybe, there is some other library that I could use, that can do, what I require?

Comment: I think I understand what the OP wants to do and I have done exactly that. If the ”on hold” is lifted I will provide an answer.

Comment: magjac, perhaps, I will wait for a half of a day and if they won't lift the "on hold" status, I can create another question, and you can answer there?

Comment: Please provide your DOT source and state which element you want to find the correspondace to. Also rephrase the question to ask for exactly that. Otherwise it will probably be put on hold again

Comment: magjac, I edited

Comment: I've suggested a better title. Hopefully the "on hold" will be lifted now. Your code is a little more complicated than I thought. You want to be able to reference individual label record fields. I'll look into that. In the meantime, have a look at [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/28a70231e2c9dddb84b3b20f450a215f) that shows how to associate node and edge SVG elements with DOT source elements. It uses [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) (based on [viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/)), but the same can be accomplished with viz.js directly

Comment: Thanks, this is a headstart! I will play with it. So, I need to use D3 lib for that. When they remove hold, and you promote your comment to an answer, I will vote check (vote) for it. If you want, I will create a new question with the same title and the contents, and remove this one. You post your answer there and I will checkbox it.

Comment: It's up to you. I'll gladly post wherever you like. We can wait until this evening (CET) though, because  I'm not yet finished with a solution and I have to code for money during the day.

Comment: See a solution in [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/magjac/18da096e75304b81871adc1d594039c8). I will explain it when I can post a proper answer. @GerardoFurtado: please lift the "on hold"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In cases simpler that yours, the SVG `<title>` element can be used to refer back to nodes and edges. For nodes, the title is the "[*node_id*](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language)" (not to be confused with the node attribute [*id*](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#did)) and for edges it is "[*node_id*](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) [*edgeop*](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) [*node_id*](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language)", e.g. `a -> b`. From your SVG code:

`<g id="node1" class="node">
   <title>person</title>`

`person` can be used to refer back to the DOT source line: `person [...`.

In the general case, the Graphviz [id](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:id) attribute is your friend:

> ***id***
>
> Allows the graph author to provide an id for graph objects which is to be included in the output. Normal "\N", "\E", "\G" substitutions are applied. If provided, it is the responsibility of the provider to keep its values sufficiently unique for its intended downstream use. Note, in particular, that "\E" does not provide a unique id for multi-edges. If no id attribute is provided, then a unique internal id is used. However, this value is unpredictable by the graph writer. An externally provided id is not used internally.
>
> If the graph provides an id attribute, this will be used as a prefix for internally generated attributes. By making these distinct, the user can include multiple image maps in the same document.

In your case, you want to reference not only nodes, but also individual fields of [record-based nodes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record).

Although the fields of record labels are defined with *fieldId*'s, they do not seem to be intended to propagate to the generated SVG:

> The first string in fieldId assigns a portname to the field and can be combined with the node name to indicate where to attach an edge to the node. (See portPos.)

To your rescue comes [HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html):

> The record-based shape has largely been superseded and greatly generalized by HTML-like labels. That is, instead of using shape=record, one might consider using shape=none, margin=0 and an HTML-like label.

With them you can create a node that is a table with rows and columns where you *can* use the ***ID*** attribute:

> ID="value"
>
> allows the user to specify a unique ID for a table or cell. See the id attribute for more information. Note that the "value" is treated as an escString similarly to the id attribute.

Unfortunately there is [a bug](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/207) in Graphviz (better described [here](http://ftp.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2197)) that causes this attribute to be ignored in the SVG output. Fortunately, there's a [workaround](http://ftp.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2197#c302).

Below is a solution which is based on [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz), which uses [viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/) internally. You don't need to use d3-graphviz, though. You can achieve the same thing with viz.js directly.

If you keep your id's sufficiently unique and you have control of the formatting of the DOT source, you can use simple pattern replacement as in the presented solution.

If you don't have control over the formatting of the DOT source, you are probably better off feeding back the information to the application that generates it. An alternative, to avoid writing a full-fledged DOT parser, is to normalize the DOT source with viz.js by using 'dot' as output format and try to parse that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@0.1.2/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

var dotSrc = `
digraph DB {
graph [label="Click on a cell to convert to upper/lower case" labelloc="t", fontsize="20.0" tooltip=" "]
rankdir=LR
node [shape=plain]

person [

    // NOTE: The use of HREF is a workaround for '[Dot] ID="value" fails to produce id string in svg:svg output for html nodes'
    //       See https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/207
    //       For the workaorund and more info, see http://ftp.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2197

    label=< <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
              <TR><TD>Person table</TD></TR>
              <TR><TD ID="p.id" PORT="id" HREF=" ">Person ID</TD></TR>
              <TR><TD ID="p.fn" PORT="fn" HREF=" ">First Name</TD></TR>
              <TR><TD ID="p.mn" PORT="mn" HREF=" ">Middle Name</TD></TR>
              <TR><TD ID="p.ln" PORT="ln" HREF=" ">Last Name</TD></TR>
            </TABLE> >
]

address [
    label=< <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
        <TR><TD>Addresses table</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.id" PORT="id" HREF=" ">Address ID</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.pid" PORT="pid" HREF=" ">Person ID</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.index" PORT="index" HREF=" ">ZIP Code</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.street" PORT="street" HREF=" ">Street Name</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.house" PORT="house" HREF=" ">House Number</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.town" PORT="town" HREF=" ">City/Town/Village Name</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.state" PORT="state" HREF=" ">State Name</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.district" PORT="district" HREF=" ">County/District Name</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="a.country" PORT="country" HREF=" ">Country Name</TD></TR>
      </TABLE> >
]

phone [
    label=< <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
        <TR><TD>Phone Number table</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="n.pid" PORT="pid" HREF=" ">Person ID</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="n.cc" PORT="cc" HREF=" ">Country Code</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="n.ac" PORT="ac" HREF=" ">Area Code</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD ID="n.n" PORT="n" HREF=" ">Phone Number</TD></TR>
      </TABLE> >
]
{phone:pid address:pid} -> person:id

}
`;

var graphviz = d3.select("#graph").graphviz();
var dotSrcLines;

function render(dotSrc) {
//    console.log('DOT source =', dotSrc);
    dotSrcLines = dotSrc.split('\n');

    transition1 = d3.transition()
        .delay(100)
        .duration(1000);

    graphviz
        .transition(transition1)
        .renderDot(dotSrc);

    transition1
      .transition()
        .duration(0)
        .on("end", function () {
            nodes = d3.selectAll('.node,.edge');
            nodes
              .selectAll("g")
                .on("click", fieldClickHandler)
              .selectAll("a")
                // Remove the workaround attributes to avoid consuming the click events
                .attr("href", null)
                .attr("title", null);
        });
}

function fieldClickHandler () {
    var node = d3.select(this);
    var text = node.selectAll('text').text();
    var id = node.attr('id');
    var class1 = node.attr('class');
    dotElement = id.replace(/^a_/, '');
    console.log('Element id="%s" class="%s" text="%s" dotElement="%s"', id, class1, text, dotElement);
    console.log('Finding and deleting references to %s "%s" from the DOT source', class1, dotElement);
    for (i = 0; i < dotSrcLines.length; i++) {
        if (dotSrcLines[i].indexOf(dotElement) >= 0) {
            ucText = text.toUpperCase();
            lcText = text.toLowerCase();
            if (text != ucText) {
                newText = ucText;
            } else {
                newText = lcText;
            }
            console.log('Converting "%s" to "%s" on line %d: %s', text, newText, i, dotSrcLines[i]);
            dotSrcLines[i] = dotSrcLines[i].replace(text, newText);
        }
    }
    dotSrc = dotSrcLines.join('\n');
    render(dotSrc);
}

render(dotSrc);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanx for for help. As a matter of fact, I've had a thought, that if all fails, I would have to use HTML in GraphViz source, but I wanted to leave it as a last resort, as it would mercilessly bloat the GraphViz source and make it barely readable. I was hoping, that there is some feature in the actual viz.js or d3.js or some other js lib, that would actually generate the svg with the ids, that could be used further to tie the generated graph to the source, or maybe these libraries create an object, taht's ties the source graphviz and the generated svg together, that I didn't know about,

Comment: but, on the other hand, when I was reading your answer and got to the point of you suggesting HTML in graphviz source, then it dawned on me - I can have the HTMLless graphviz source, than right before passing it to the viz.js, I can preprocess it with HTML, and when the changes on SVG will need to be saved back to the source graphviz, they will actually be saved to the HTMLless version, bypassing the HTML version alltogether. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Graphviz accepts [`class` attributes](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/class/) and outputs them as SVG `class="foo"`. Example:

```
$ cat test.dot
digraph G {
  graph [class="cats"];

  subgraph cluster_big {
    graph [class="big_cats"];

    "Lion" [class="yellow social"];
    "Snow Leopard" [class="white solitary"];
  };
}

$ dot -Tsvg ~/test.dot | grep "<g"
<g id="graph0" class="graph cats" ...>
<g id="clust1" class="cluster big_cats">
<g id="node1" class="node yellow social">
<g id="node2" class="node white solitary">
```